# Symfony form : dynamic default value for one field

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

There is a list of championships each with its own list of the events. Each championship has a button to open a modal with the form to create a new event. As it's the same form for all new events, I just want to be able to pass the value (EntityType "championship") to the form when the appropriate button is clicked. Meaning if I click the button of "championship A", the form have to get the preselected "championship A".
I understand that I need somehow include js in there but don't see how to connect them all knowing that the value must be of EntityType. Do you have any advice?

Heres it the form builder:

```
        $builder
            ->add('name', ChoiceType::class,[
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
                'choices'=>[
                    $currentYear=> $currentYear,
                    $nextYear => $nextYear
                ],
                'empty_data'=>$currentYear
            ])
            ->add('year')
            ->add('location')
            ->add('country')
          ->add('championship', EntityType::class, [

                'class' => Championship::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
            ])
        ;
```

Twig vue:

```
    <div class="row mt-4">
            {% set currentYear = "now"|date("Y") %}
            <h2>Championships {{ currentYear }}</h2>
            <div >

                {% for champ in champs %}


                    <ul class="my-2">
                        <li class="row">
                            <p>{{ champ.name }} <a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i></a></p>

                        </li>

                                <ul>
                                    {% for event in champ.event %}

                                        {% if event.year  == currentYear%}
                                            <li><a href="{{ path('event_info',{ id:event.id}) }}">{{ event.name }}</a></li>
                                        {% endif %}

                                    {% endfor %}
                                </ul>
                    </ul>

                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">New Event</h1>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            {{ form_start(form) }}
                            {{ form_end(form) }}

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col ">

            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by updating the form's data before rendering it in the modal. You can do this by passing the championship ID as a data attribute on the button and then using JavaScript to update the hidden championship field of the form with the championship ID when the modal is opened.

1. Add a data attribute to the button with the championship ID:

```
<a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-championship-id="{{ champ.id }}"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i></a>
```

2. Add a hidden field for the championship ID in the form:

```
 $builder
    ->add('championship', HiddenType::class)
    ->add('name', TextType::class)
    // other form fields
;
```

3. Use JavaScript to update the hidden championship field when the modal is opened:

```
<script>
    var myModalEl = document.getElementById('exampleModal')
    myModalEl.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = event.relatedTarget
        var championshipId = button.getAttribute('data-championship-id')
        var form = myModalEl.querySelector('form')
        var championshipField = form.querySelector('[name="form[championship]"]')
        championshipField.value = championshipId
    })
</script>
```